# Leaflet WFS point map with custom symbols and popups

Tags: leaflet

I have a data set which contains points of interest. This is stored on Geoserver.

I am creating a web map which pulls in these points as a WFS from Geoserver and displays the points.

I want the points to be a different icon to the standard Leaflet blue marker. I also need the map to have a popup with the details of the POI when the marker is clicked.

My issue is that the marker is not changing from the blue marker. The popups work and the markers are in the correct location but the marker symbol is not the .png image that I have designed.

Here is my code:

```
//Create the Points of interest WFS Layer

    //Style for POI Icon
    var POIIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'Images/defult.png', **//This is correct file path**
        iconSize: [20,20]
    });

    var owsrootUrl = 'http://geodev.co.za:8080/geoserver/SoapToAlaska/ows';
    var defaultParameters = {
        service : 'WFS',
        version : '1.0.0',
        request : 'GetFeature',
        typeName : 'SoapToAlaska:PointsOfInterestWithPitlatrines',
        outputFormat : 'text/javascript',
        format_options : 'callback:getJson',
        SrsName : 'EPSG:4326'
    };
    var parameters = L.Util.extend(defaultParameters);
    var URL = owsrootUrl + L.Util.getParamString(parameters);

    var PointsOfInterest = null;
    var ajax = $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        success : function (response) {
            PointsOfInterest = L.geoJson(response, {
                style: function (feature) {
                    return {icon: POIIcon}; **//This is the part that doesn't seem to be working**
                },                  
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                    layer.bindPopup("Type: " + feature.properties.type, popupOptions);
                }
            })

        //Load WaterSources and PointsOfInterest WFS layers from ajax into the layer control
            LC.addOverlay(PointsOfInterest,"PointsOfInterest");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the icon directly to the marker instead over `style`:

```
 var ajax = $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        jsonpCallback : 'getJson',
        success : function (response) {
            PointsOfInterest = L.geoJson(response, {               
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    popupOptions = {maxWidth: 200};
                    layer.bindPopup("Type: " + feature.properties.type, popupOptions);
                    layer.setIcon(POIIcon);
                }
            })

        //Load WaterSources and PointsOfInterest WFS layers from ajax into the layer control
            LC.addOverlay(PointsOfInterest,"PointsOfInterest");
        }
    });
```